# Writing debuggers

Tags: c++, windows, debugging

I am very dissatisfied at how little info is available on writing Windows debuggers.

Most of the code I have was made by a long process of trial and error, the documentation obviously "thinks" most of the topics are too trivial while explaining in much detail obvious and useless things.

I found 2 articles or so on it but not much stuff I didn't already know came out of it.

Is there any documentation at all, and I mean complete documentation, or some GOOD article (not how to change a byte to 0xCC in vb.NET but real world stuff) about debuggers? Advanced debuggers with memory breakpoints.

For now I didn't find a way for example how to find out how many bytes were being written in a GUARD_PAGE_VIOLATION. I just make a buffer before and after the code executes and compare.

Also where to find info what lies in `debug_event.u.Exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionInformation`? (among other things that lay in debug_event)

Do I really have to reverse the reversing environment myself?

Comment: I am pretty sure you will not find anything. Interaction between debugger and kernel is obscure and unclear even to MS itself.

Comment: DEBUG_EVENT is officially described in MSDN here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679308(v=vs.85).aspx .Some nice articles are here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/132742/Writing-Windows-Debugger-Part-2 and here: http://devonstrawntech.tumblr.com/post/15878429193/how-to-write-a-windows-debugger-references

Comment: @SimonMourier post it as an answer, that second link has tons of info, thanks :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is indeed some information available.

DEBUG_EVENT (and the rest of the Debug API) is officially described in MSDN here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679308(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679308%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

There is a nice CodeProject article: [Writing a basic Windows debugger](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43682/Writing-a-basic-Windows-debugger) and its sequel: [Writing Windows Debugger - Part 2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/132742/Writing-Windows-Debugger-Part-2)

And finally, a complete list of references from Devon Strawn: [How to write a (Windows) debugger - References](http://devonstrawntech.tumblr.com/post/15878429193/how-to-write-a-windows-debugger-references)

Answer (score 2):

You can find "old" but good samples in the Windows SDK:
Look at: .\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Samples\winbase\debug\

The debbughandler shows how to handle exceptions.

Comment: Since you can't add a comment, try to include some sources and/or other examples.